# Multiple references from one entity to another, database schema, Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, database-schema

Read it several times and understood that i'm not so good in asking questions correctly. Made some corrections to the question.

I have 2 classes in my app: `Contractor` and `ContractorGroup`.

1. Each `Contractor` has a parent `Contractor`. Parent `Contractor` can see only it's dependants. And can not see dependants of it's dependants. Only one level of visibility.
2. Parent `Contractor` can group it's dependant `Contractors` into `ContractorGroup`.

   So, many dependant `Contractors` for one `ContractorGroup` (many-to-one)
   `Contractor` has a NavProperty `ContractorGroup`, the group to which it belongs. Each `Contractor` can be ONLY IN ONE `ContractorGroup`.

**Example:**
I'm the parent `Contractor` and have 5 dependant `Contractors` and i want to group first 2 of them into 1st`ContractorGroup` and last 3 to 2nd`ContractorGroup`.
So, options to implement:

***First:*** I can not to include FK(`VisibleToContractorId` - id of my parent `Contractor`) in `ContractorGroup` which connects each of 2 groups to parent `Contractor`.
In this case i can do query similar to:

```
    var ContractorGroupsToDispalayForParentContractor =
context.ContractorGroups.Where(p => p.Contractors.All(p => p.Parent == ParentContractor));
```

In other words: "Find all groups which consist of contractors with parent == ParentContractor"
In this option everything works fine. DbSchema is simple and clear. But i dont like the query.


 ***Second:*** Or i can introduce FK(`VisibleToContractorId`). So one parent `Contractor` has many `ContractorGroups` which consist of dependant `Contractors`. Then i have a simplier and more robust query:

```
    var ContractorGroupsToDispalayForParentContractor = 
context.ContractorGroups.Where(p => p.VisibleToContractor == ParentContractor);
```

This query i like. But EF introduces strange DbColumn which is ALWAYS `null`. >:-E

Short db schema:

```
Table("Contractor")
ContractorId = PK
ContractorGroupId = FK
ContractorGroup_ContractorGroupId = FK <--- This One

Table("ContratorGroup")
ContractorGroupId = PK
VisibleToContractorId = FK
```

**My domain Classes and EntityConfiguration:**

```
public class Contractor : IObjectWithState
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int ContractorId { get; set; }

    public virtual Contractor Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual int? ParentId { get; set; }

    public virtual ContractorGroup ContractorGroup { get; set; }
    public virtual int? ContractorGroupId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ContractorGroup> GroupsVisible { get; set; } 
 }

public class ContractorGroup : IObjectWithState
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int ContractorGroupId { get; set; }

    public virtual Contractor VisibleToContractor { get; set; }
    public virtual int? VisibleToContractorId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Contractor> Contractors { get; set; }            
}
```

Entity configurations (only in `ContractorGroupConfiguration`):

```
HasMany(p => p.Contractors).WithOptional(p=>p.ContractorGroup);
HasOptional(p => p.VisibleToContractor).WithMany(
       p=>p.GroupsVisible).HasForeignKey(p=>p.VisibleToContractorId);
```

Is it a bug in EF?
What implementation ***First*** or ***Second*** of domain model would you prefer?

Thanks.

Comment: Some questions: _all data for this contractor is only visible to its parent Contractor_ what is _all data_ and how is this rule related to the references in question? Is it intentional that a `Contractor` can belong to only one `ContractorGroup`? If so, what is the meaning of _Contractors can have visible only to them (their?) ContractorGroups_? In short: the association looks more like many-to-many to me.

Comment: Thank you. I made corrections to my question. Maybe now it is more clear what i intend to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that you need to tell EF that the associations `ContractorGroup.VisibleToContractor` and `Contractor.GroupsVisible` are no independent associations (with two FK fields), but are two parts of a bidirectional association. Replace the entity configurations by:

```
class ContractorConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Contractor>
{
    public ContractorConfiguration()
    {
        HasMany(c => c.GroupsVisible).WithOptional(g => g.VisibleToContractor);
    }
}
```

Without this, EF creates the field `ContractorGroup_ContractorGroupId` as a FK for `Contractor.GroupsVisible` on top of the FK `VisibleToContractorId`.